# parameters definitions conflicts

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, final

I try to implement a game in java with 'MCV' pattern, 
and I have a conflict about how to define some parameters in the 'view' class.

Is it correct to make the width and height of the JFrame and paths of images as 'final static' variables, that define at the start? or define in the builder?
or I don't need to save them as 'final static', but get them on the builder parameters from the 'control' class?

I will be happy for recommendations and explanations for any solution.
thank you :)

Comment: Why do you think they should be static? And why final? What do you want to happen if the user wants to stretch or shrink the frame?

Comment: I was thinking that:
final - because I don't want that the size of the frame (the game board width  & height), as well as the images (the paths that implement the images), will change at the middle of the game. 
static - it will help that the 'model' class will know the size of the game-board 
(it could make objects stay in the board borders), and because it is final I don't care to share it with all the class. 
but I don't know if that good way of thinking